# gunicorn_start error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

Tags: django, linux, gunicorn

Al configurar Gunicorn_start, me devuelve el siguiente error:

**Error:**

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '/webapps/retegienv/retegiwebrep/retegiweb/retegiweb'

**gunicorn_start**

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="retegiweb"
DJANGODIR=/webapps/retegienv/retegiwebrep/retegiweb/retegiweb
SOCKFILE=/webapps/retegienv/run/gunicorn.sock
USER=root                                       
GROUP=root                                  
NUM_WORKERS=3    
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=/webapps/retegienv/retegiwebrep/retegiweb/retegiweb.settings             
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=/webapps/retegienv/retegiwebrep/retegiweb/retegiweb.wsgi                     
echo "Starting $NAME as `whoami`"

cd $DJANGODIR
source ../../../bin/activate
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH


RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR

exec ../../../bin/gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
  --user=$USER --group=$GROUP \
  --bind=unix:$SOCKFILE \
  --log-level=debug \
  --log-file=-
```

Comment: Editado. Gracias Mauricio Contreras. ; )